# Closure of the range of a compact operator

Tags: functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, banach-spaces, compact-operators

Let $X$ be an infinite-dimensional Banach space, and let $Y$ be a banach. Let $T$ be a compact operator from $X$ to $Y$, ie. if $(x_n)$ is a sequence in $X$ then there is a subsequence s.t. $T(x_{n(k)})$ converges. We wish to show that 0 is in the closure of $\{Tx,||x||=1\}$.

I've been working on this problem for a while, and have been entirely unable to solve it without resorting to the spectral theorem, but I've been told there is an elementary solution involving only the fact that we can find a sequence of unit vectors $X$ s.t. that the distance between the elements is greater than or zero (ie. Riesz Lemma).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you have a continuous linear operator $A\colon X \to Y$ with $X$ and $Y$ as in the question, such that $0$ is not in the (norm) closure of $\{ Ax : \lVert x\rVert_X = 1\}$. Then

$$\delta := \inf \{\lVert Ax\rVert_Y : \lVert x\rVert_X = 1\} > 0.$$

Hence $A$ is injective, and $A$ is an open mapping to $\mathcal{R}(A)$; we have $\delta\lVert x\rVert_X \leqslant \lVert Ax\rVert_Y \leqslant \lVert A\rVert\cdot\lVert x\rVert_X$ for all $x\in X$, so $A^{-1} \colon \mathcal{R}(A) \to X$ is continuous, with $\lVert A^{-1}\rVert = \delta^{-1}$. Therefore $\mathcal{R}(A)$ is a Banach space (if $(Ax_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence in $\mathcal{R}(A)$, then $(x_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence in $X$, hence convergent, $x_n \to x_\ast$, and then $Ax_n \to Ax_\ast$ by the continuity of $A$). Since $A$ is injective, $\mathcal{R}(A)$ is infinite-dimensional. Hence $\overline{A(B_X)}$, which is a neighbourhood of $0$ in $\mathcal{R}(A)$ is not compact (since only finite-dimensional Hausdorff topological vector spaces are locally compact [Riesz]). Therefore $A$ is not compact.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer! I may be having a dull moment, but might it be possible to elaborate your answer a bit? Unless I am misreading your answer, you're implying that no compact operator is injective if it goes from an infinite dimensional Banach space?

Comment: No, compact operators can be injective fine. They cannot be _open mappings_ if they have infinite-dimensional (complete) range. Because that would imply that the closed unit ball in the range wold be compact.

Comment: Ah, of course. I think I've managed to confuse myself completely with this problem, and I apologize in advance if any of the following is completely wrong. 

If $T$ is a compact operator, $X$ an infinite dimensional Banach-space, then $\mathcal{R}(T)$ is finite dimensional. This implies (why?) that the infimum of $T$ taken on the unit sphere must be zero.

Comment: No, $\mathcal{R}(T)$ can be infinite-dimensional. Consider $T \colon \ell^p \to \ell^p;\; T(x_n) = \left(\frac1n x_n\right)$. But then its range cannot be closed. I have changed the wording of the answer, hopefully that makes it clearer.

Comment: With the clarification i see why it must hold, thank you. You've just saved me from another frustrating day.